# I am confused about the keyword 'this' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope, this

This is an example:

```
function one() {

    var a = 1;
    two();

    function two() {

        var b = 2;
        three();

        function three() {

            var c = 3;
            alert(a + b + c); // 6

        }
    }   
}

one()​; //calling the function
```

Now when we call function one(), the result is `6`.

So it's all about scope chain, all variables are resolved, now I have one question.

Why do we need this "*this*" keyword when all variables are getting resolved through scope chain?

So if we have the following function:

```
function a() {
    var a = 'function a';

    function b() {
        var b = 'function b';
        alert (a); //will be function a, without keyword this 
        alert (this.a); // what will be the effect of this line
    }
}
```

The "this" keyword always confuses me!

Someone please explain in a simple way and in detail.

Comment: Read this : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: this is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 3):

They keyword `this` is resolved in the following ways in the a function in JavaScript -

1. When a function is invoked on or through an object, that object is the invocation
   context or 'this' value for the function. For example -

   ```
   var o = {
      f : function(){
         //do something  
      }
   }
   ```

   if we call the method 'f' of object 'o' using object 'o' -

   ```
   o.f()// in method f, 'this' refers to o inside the method o
   ```
2. If the function is not invoked on or not through an object,current window object is the invocation context or `this` value for the function. For example -

   ```
   function f(){
       //do something
   }

   //calling f
   f();// 'this' will refer to current window object
   ```

In your case, this refers to current window object and `this.a` is a reference to the function a, which you have defined in the global scope.

In addition, invocation context or 'this' value for the function can be supplied while calling it. Please check [Function.prototype.call method - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [Function.prototype.apply method - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Answer (score 0):

The this keyword refers to the scope of the function. In your above code the **this.a** will print **undefined** since there is no variable named a. The **this keyword is used to refer the current local scope** and not the global scope. so if you had a variable named a in your function b then this.a will refer the variable defined in the function b and not outside of it. Whereas referring this outside the function b will refer the global scope.